# How to store multiple checkbox items in a single fields of users table so that if i want to search specific items i can do that in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

[I want to store it in single field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XEpm.png)

[And when i search for single item it will find it out from that field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8oo3.png)

Comment: store value of checkbox comma separated and fetch the value in an array string to split with comma. and search value to the string[] array;

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as json or array.

like this

```
["nursery", "U.K.G.(Upper Kinder Garten)", "STD Two"]
```

In `get` query, you can have them by using `LIKE` in your query.

```
return Model::where('your_column_name', 'LIKE', '%" . $request->value . "%')->get();
```